# Avro SpecificSchemaCompiler null pointer exception

Tags: avro, avro-tools

I am trying to generate avro java classes programmatically. I have defined avro schema file. I am invoking SpecificSchemaCompiler object with this schema and then calling compileToDestination(src,dest) method to get the generated class. However I am facing a null pointer exception.

The above issue I faced in my existing workspace. So I created a new java project in eclipse and simply tried the above approach. There it worked and I am getting the generate java file.

I am using the following schema.

{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "gov.mrm",
     "name": "Customer",
     "doc": "Avro Schema for our Customer",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "first_name", "type": "string", "doc": "First Name of Customer" },
       { "name": "last_name", "type": "string", "doc": "Last Name of Customer" },
       { "name": "age", "type": "int", "doc": "Age at the time of registration" },
       { "name": "height", "type": "float", "doc": "Height at the time of registration in cm" },
       { "name": "weight", "type": "float", "doc": "Weight at the time of registration in kg" },
       { "name": "automated_email", "type": "boolean", "default": true, "doc": "Field indicating if the user is enrolled in marketing emails" }
     ]
}

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    SpecificCompiler compiler = new SpecificCompiler(new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("src/main/avro/customer.avsc")));
    compiler.compileToDestination(new File("src/main/avro"), new File("src/main/java"));
}
```

}

I am getting following exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.avro.compiler.specific.SpecificCompiler.renderTemplate(SpecificCompiler.java:387)
    at org.apache.avro.compiler.specific.SpecificCompiler.compile(SpecificCompiler.java:456)
    at org.apache.avro.compiler.specific.SpecificCompiler.compileToDestination(SpecificCompiler.java:374)
    at main.avro.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:831)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:813)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:470)
    at org.apache.avro.compiler.specific.SpecificCompiler.renderTemplate(SpecificCompiler.java:385)
    ... 3 more

Comment: can you provide avro schema file that you try to compile ? do you get the same error if you pass the schema in a string instead of read it from a file ?

Comment: Hello. I have updated the schema. I am still not sure about the two parameters of the compileToDestination. Any help in explaining those parameters is appreciated.